# Filling an empty vector with values relative to the first value in the vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector:

```
sample.vector
      1
      1
      0
      0
      14
      1
      1
      0
      1
      12
```

I created a second vector with the following code:

```
second.vector <- c(1, rep(NA, length(sample.vector)))
```

Which made this:

```
second.vector
      1
      NA
      NA
      NA
      NA
      NA
      NA
      NA
      NA
      NA
      NA
```

I want to populate `second.vector` such that the `NA`s are replaced with 0 + the value in the row above it (i.e. the 1 in the first row of second vector) if `sample.vector < 3` or 1 + the value in the row above it (i.e. whatever that value may be) if `sample.vector > 3`.

In other words:

> R, I want you to look at row[n] in `sample.vector`. If the value is less than three, I want you to replace the NA in `second.vector` with the value above that NA. If the value in row[n] is greater than 3, I want you to fill the NA in `second.vector` with the value above that NA, but add 1 to it.
>
> Do this for every row within `sample.vector` so that every `NA` in `second.vector` is replaced with values.

So the vector that I'm hoping to get is:

```
second.vector
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      2
      2
      2
      2
      2
      3
```

I've tried this:

```
second.vector[2:length(second.vector)] <- 
    ifelse(sample.vector[1:length(sample.vector)] > 3, 
    second.vector[1:length(second.vector)]+1, 
    second.vector[1:length(second.vector)]+0)
```

But it just gives the second row of `second.vector` a 1, rather than filling up the entire vector.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: `cumsum(as.numeric(sample.vector > 3)) + 1 `

Comment: what if the value = 3?

Comment: @bouncyball This is just an example; the data I have is such that the values are either 1,0, or grossly larger than 2 or 3

Comment: @cuttlefis44 that actually worked really beautifully. That was embarrassingly simple, thanks so much!

Comment: @cuttlefish44, you can post that as an answer with a little explanation.

Comment: @cuttlefish44 the `as.numeric` call is unnecessary

Comment: @Axeman; you're right, I followed it. @Pierre Lafortune; Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cumsum()` returns cumulative sums. For example, `cumsum(c(3, 7, 1))` is `[1] 3  10  11`

```
sample.vector <- c(1,1,0,0,14,1,1,0,1,12)
library(dplyr) # just to explain

(sample.vector > 3) %>% # [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
  as.numeric()  %>%     # [1] 0 0 0 0 1 ...  # but this line is unnecessary, thanks @Pierre Lafortune
    cumsum()  %>%       # [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2  # do cumulative sums
      + 1               # [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3  # what you want

# summarizing the above,
cumsum(sample.vector > 3) + 1
```